# In Scala, does a no-more-referenced object can be garbage collected during flatMap?

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, flatmap

We use `flatMap` (in for comprehension) to chain long serie of can-fail things. So we have a lot of methods that return something like an `Either`, like that:

```
// point-0
for {
  // point-1
  a <- createBigObject
  // point-2
  b <- doSomeTransformationOn(a)
  // point-3
  c <- sameBWichCanBeLong
} yield {
  // point-4
  c
}
// point-5
```

In our case, `a` is very big. We don't want to keep it around more than necessary.

My question is: can `a` can be garbage collected at `point-3` (because it is not more referenced after that)? 
If not, is there some option in `scalac` that can make it be so? 
If not, how the code should be refactor to make it possible ?

Comment: Why don't you run the code with a profiler and verify what happens? Why would you bother to optimize something which hasn't be a problem yet? _(remember that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil")_ - Also, garbage collection is not a problem of the **Scala compiler**, is a problem of the runtime environment in your case the **JVM**, but things may be different if you run in **JS** or in **Native** or in **GraalVM**.

Comment: it is a problem, that's why I want to optimize. A profiler does not help much for now, I would like to know what *theorically* should happen. And it is *also* a problem of `scalac` because it's it which does some escape analysis and generate the bytecode.

Comment: _theorically_ nothing should happen, on the language level memory, cpu, disk, etc either not exist or you could think about them like infinite resources. so, things like garbage collection are not to be reasoned from the language point of view. As I said, that is a problem of the _runtime_ system. A profiler could help you identify what exactly is the problem, and maybe even give you suggestions, Also, you may try using other runtimes, another version of the **JVM** or another distro like **Graal** or **OpenJ9**.

Comment: No, an operational semantic is bound to the language. Resources are not infinite, and it's why in scala, even for pure-FP, we have to deal with `trampoling` things. The compiler is responsible for where variable are declared and what are their scope at bytecode level. Compiler optimization are a thing for real.

Comment: Thinking about this for a while, I realized that each `a` can not be free until `createBigObject` isn't referred any more. Which will not happen until the end of the **for comprenhension**. Maybe doing this `val step1 = createBigObject` - `val step2 = step1.flatMap(doSomeTransformationOn)` -  _etc_. So instead of nested flatMap calls, you would one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I made some test which are as bad as what `System.gc()` allows. I would still love to know, by someone with internal knowledge of `scalac` and/or `jvm` spec, what is expected behavior.

The code below is run with `scalac 2.12, with following options:

```
-target:jvm-1.8
-Ypartial-unification
-Xcheckinit
-Xfuture
-Xlint:_,-nullary-unit,-missing-interpolator
-Yno-adapted-args
-Ywarn-dead-code
-Ywarn-extra-implicit
-Ywarn-inaccessible
-Ywarn-infer-any
-Ywarn-nullary-override
-Ywarn-numeric-widen
-Ywarn-unused:imports
-Ywarn-unused:locals
-Ywarn-unused:privates
```

Edit: adding `-opt:_` leads to the same results.

- test-0 seems to indicate that object are not released during the whole `for`
- test-1 seems to indicate that a nice little scoping allows object to be released
- test-2 is as expected, but test-3 is strange: I don't know why objects can't be released at `t3`.

```
package com.normation

import scala.concurrent.Future
object CheckMemoryReleaseFlatMap {


  def getFreeMem = (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / (1024*1024)).toString + " MB"
  def doGC = {
    System.gc()
    System.runFinalization()
  }

  // this array is 200MB
  def newBigArray() = Array.fill(50 * 1024)(Array.fill(1024)("x"))

  implicit val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global

  /*
   * Configuring jvm with -Xmx500M -Xms500M
   */

  def test0(): Unit = {
    Future {
      doGC
      println("t0: " + getFreeMem)                   // t0: 493 MB
      doGC
      for {
        a <- Some(newBigArray())
        _ = doGC
        _ =  println("t1: " + getFreeMem)            // t1: 292 MB
        _ = doGC
        b <- Some(newBigArray())
        _ = doGC
        _ =  println("t2: " + getFreeMem)            // t2:  91 MB
        _ = doGC
      } yield {
        doGC
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println("t3: " + getFreeMem)                 // t3:  91 MB
        Unit
      }
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000)
    doGC
    println("t4: " + getFreeMem)                     // t4: 493 MB

  }

  def test1(): Unit = {
    Future {
      doGC
      println("t0: " + getFreeMem)                   // t4: 493 MB
      doGC
      for {
        x <- for {
                a <- Some(newBigArray())
                _ = doGC
                _ =  println("t1: " + getFreeMem)    // t1: 292 MB
                _ = doGC
                b <- Some(newBigArray())
             } yield b
        _ = doGC
        _ =  println("t2: " + getFreeMem)            // t2: 292 MB
        _ = doGC
      } yield {
        doGC
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println("t3: " + getFreeMem)                 // t3: 292 MB
        Unit
      }
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000)
    doGC
    println("t4: " + getFreeMem)                     // t4: 493 MB
  }

  def test2(): Unit = {
    doGC
    println("t0: " + getFreeMem)                     // t0: 493 MB
    doGC
    val a = Some(newBigArray())
    doGC
    println("t1: " + getFreeMem)                     // t1: 292 MB
    doGC
    val b = Some(newBigArray())
    doGC
    println("t2: " + getFreeMem)                     // t2:  91 MB
  }

  def test3(): Unit = {
    doGC
    println("t0: " + getFreeMem)                     // t0: 493 MB
    doGC

    {
      val a = Some(newBigArray())
      doGC
      println("t1: " + getFreeMem)                   // t1: 292 MB
      doGC
      val b = Some(newBigArray())
      doGC
      println("t2: " + getFreeMem)                   // t2:  91 MB
    }
    doGC
    println("t3: " + getFreeMem)                     // t3:  91 MB  => ????
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("======= test 0 ========")
    test0
    doGC
    println("======= test 1 ========")
    test1
    doGC
    println("======= test 2 ========")
    test2
    doGC
    println("======= test 3 ========")
    test3
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that `System.gc` is not guaranteed to free memory; it's at best a suggestion to the JVM that a full garbage collection be run.  The absence of blocking on the `Future`s is also a potential confound.